# How to set child index path without specific parent id in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have route.rb like this:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :company_jobs
end
```

And rails routes:

```
 company_company_jobs GET    /companies/:company_id/company_jobs(.:format)  company_jobs#index
```

I need to add a link to show all company_jobs model without specific company_id like this:

```
<a href="<%=company_company_jobs_path%>"></a>
```

Any one how can I config route to do this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your routing implies is that you want all company_jobs that belong to company identified by :id.   Assuming that you have a model association set up between the two models, this would be referenced as <%= link_to company_company_jobs(@company) %> - rails will fill in the id for you.

If instead, you just want to include all jobs no matter which company, you could change your routes to:

```
  resources :companies do
    collection do
      get :company_jobs
    end
    resources :company_jobs
  end
```

This will create a new route `companies_company_jobs_path   company#company_jobs`
For this route to work, you will need to add the following to companies_controller.rb

```
def company_jobs
end
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I found another way for list all company_jobs without company id : get 'company_job_list' => 'company_jobs#list'. This routes will allow me for call company_job_list_path without company id, and all company_jobs will call in list function of controller